# Why am not getting any output for this program to bubble sort an array using recursion?

Tags: c, arrays

What I tried doing is to run the process of sorting `(n-1)` times and hence             that `if else` condition in the main function. Since we have to use recursion I have used the `if else` ladder inside the user defined function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bin (int a[]);

int n, i, a[100], j = 0, temp, count = 0;

int main ()
{
    printf ("enter the number of elements\n");
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    printf ("enter the array elements\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf ("%d", &a[i]);

    bin (a);
    if (count == n - 1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf ("%d", a[i]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        j = 0;
        bin (a);
    }
}

int bin (int a[])
{
    if (j != n - 1 && a[j] > a[j + 1])
    {
        temp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[j + 1];
        a[j + 1] = temp;
        j++;
        bin (a);
    }
    else if (j != n - 1 && a[j] < a[j + 1])
    {
        j = j + 1;
        bin (a);
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the number of elements:

- 1 : `(count == n - 1)` is false so you do not print
- 2 : `(count == n - 1)` is always true so you print, and you sorted the array
- >1 : `(count == n - 1)` is always false so you nevert print (to be sure I used *brutal force* to check)

I also encourage you to always check the result of *scanf* to be sure a valid value was enter.

There are a lot of ways to sort using (strangely) recursion, one can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sort(int a[], int max)
{
  if (max == 0)
    return 0;

  int modified;

  if (a[0] > a[1]) {
    int v = a[0];

    a[0] = a[1];
    a[1] = v;
    modified = 1;
  }
  else
    modified = 0;

  return (sort(a + 1, max - 1) && sort(a, max - 1)) || modified;
}

int main ()
{
  int n, i;

  printf ("enter the number of elements\n");
  if ((scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) || (n <= 0))
    return -1;

  int * a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

  if (a == NULL) {
    puts("not enough memory");
    return -1;
  }

  printf ("enter the array elements\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (scanf ("%d", &a[i]) != 1) {
      puts("invalid value");
      return -1;
    }
  }

  sort(a, n - 1);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf ("%d ", a[i]);
  putchar('\n');

  free(a);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra b.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter the number of elements
1
enter the array elements
1
1 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter the number of elements
2
enter the array elements
1 2
1 2 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter the number of elements
2
enter the array elements
2 1
1 2 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
enter the number of elements
4
enter the array elements
4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider input like

```
4           // aka n
1 1 4 5     // the array elements
```

The first time you call `bin` the variable `j` has the value 0 so `a[j] > a[j + 1]` will be false (as `a[0]` is equal to `a[1]`). Likewise `a[j] < a[j + 1]` will be false. So you end up executing

```
else
{
    count++;
    return 0;
}
```

i.e. the code will increment `count` so that it becomes 1 and then the function returns.

Back in `main` the condition `(count == n - 1)` will be false so you end in this part:

```
else
{
    j = 0;
    bin (a);
}
```

where nothing is printed. Consequently - no output.